# ¿En qué parte de México se usa expresión "a wi wi"?

Tags: modismos, méxico

> A: ¡Hola, amiwoo! Kiuvas?
>
> B: ¡De perlas! ¿Qué haciendo?
>
> B: Viendo una peli y ¿tú?
>
> A: ¡A wi wi! Escuchando a Maná.

Me gustaría saber en que parte de México se usa la expresión `a wi wi`
y si es un modismo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a wi wi` es una deformación de `a huevo`, que si lo tradujeramos a algo formal sería: `por supuesto`, `claro`, `obviamente`, entre otros similares.

Es una expresión que se usa en un ámbito completamente informal y básicamente en situaciones donde existe camaradería.

En el ejemplo que mencionas, no veo mucho sentido al uso de dicha expresión, sin embargo, en conversaciones tan informales y con tanto coloquialismo es normal que se mezclen expresiones que carezcan efectivamente de significado, sin embargo, dichas expresiones no impiden que el mensaje sea entendible(por lo menos entre mexicanos).

A mi entender, `a wi wi`, es una expresión conocida en prácticamente todo México, sin llegar a ser muy común su uso.

Answer (score 0):

Es mucho más usada en el norte de México, y creo que estuvo de moda en los 90's y 00's pero hoy día ya no tanto.